# ADB commands in code

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way to run adb commands like

> adb get-state

in the code I write in eclipse

For e.g.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    testADB();
}
```

and in `testADB()` run some adb commands?

Comment: what kind of commands do you need, maybe there is a other way to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adithya , I believe you are trying to drop adb commands programmatically.Check this [link.](http://saurabh-nigam.blogspot.com/2010/10/running-android-native-code.html)

Comment: You cannot execute adb commands from android apps, but you can execute some commands that can also be (and more often are) executed via adb.

Answer (score 2):

Not literally, due to permissions and the security model.  The usb adb daemon on a consumer phone runs with slightly higher privileges than ordinary applications, so accepting commands from them would be a security hole.

However as others have pointed out, there may be alternative means to obtain some kinds of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use some of the classes in [ddmlib.jar](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git;a=blob;f=ddms/libs/ddmlib/src/com/android/ddmlib/AndroidDebugBridge.java;hb=master) for that.

Comment: I went through the Jar and didn't find anything useful for my purpose.Actually i want to get memory related information like Heap and stack information allocated for the dalvik VM ? Plus i want to get memory allocation information for each application running on the android emulator. There are options like RAM size and Heap size which we can specify while launching an AVD ?? Can anyone elaborate on it ?

Comment: The link i gave you is the Java API of adb. Maybe you should have a look at how ddms is implemented instead.

Comment: can you point me to any link as to how ddms is imeplemented ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: This is the ddms source: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git;a=tree;f=ddms/app/src/com/android/ddms;hb=HEAD